# how to read parent header <h> and <p> data using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to read corresponding header `<h1>` and paragraph `<p>` data in the following example...

I am having many headers and paragraphs which are inter related, so if I find a header then I need to extract the corresponding paragraph data:

```html
<h1>Supplementary Materials </h1>\n
    <p />\n
    <p>The workshop entitled “Next generation MRA (Microbiological Risk Assessment); integration of Omics data into assessment” took place in Athens, Greece, May 13-14, 2016, and resulted in four papers that are published in this issue, namely, Cocolin et al., Rantsiou et al., Den Besten et al., and Haddad et al. </p>\n
<h1>Testing data</h1>
    <p>The supplementary materials, Table S1 and Table S2, are integrated parts of these four papers.</p>\n
    <p />

<h1>Supplementary Materials </h1>\n
    <p />\n
    <p>The workshop entitled “Next generation MRA (Microbiological Risk Assessment); integration of Omics data into assessment” took place in Athens, Greece, May 13-14, 2016, and resulted in four papers that are published in this issue, namely, Cocolin et al., Rantsiou et al., Den Besten et al., and Haddad et al. </p>\n
<h1>Testing data</h1>
    <p>The supplementary materials, Table S1 and Table S2, are integrated parts of these four papers.</p>\n
    <p />
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please have a look at the edits I made to your question. Note how indentation is important to have the right formatting. Now you can delete the above comment. But, unfortunately your question is too broad: it lacks code. You need to pinpoint where exactly you are stuck, and ask a specific question about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the html really repeat like that or is that a typo?

```
html = '''<h1>Supplementary Materials </h1>\n
    <p />\n
    <p>The workshop entitled “Next generation MRA (Microbiological Risk Assessment); integration of Omics data into assessment” took place in Athens, Greece, May 13-14, 2016, and resulted in four papers that are published in this issue, namely, Cocolin et al., Rantsiou et al., Den Besten et al., and Haddad et al. </p>\n
<h1>Testing data</h1>
    <p>The supplementary materials, Table S1 and Table S2, are integrated parts of these four papers.</p>\n
    <p />

<h1>Supplementary Materials </h1>\n
    <p />\n
    <p>The workshop entitled “Next generation MRA (Microbiological Risk Assessment); integration of Omics data into assessment” took place in Athens, Greece, May 13-14, 2016, and resulted in four papers that are published in this issue, namely, Cocolin et al., Rantsiou et al., Den Besten et al., and Haddad et al. </p>\n
<h1>Testing data</h1>
    <p>The supplementary materials, Table S1 and Table S2, are integrated parts of these four papers.</p>\n
    <p /> '''

import bs4

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
heads = soup.find_all('h1')

for head in heads:
    para = head.find_next('p', text=True).text
    print ('Header: %s\nParagraph: %s\n' %(head.text, para))
```

**Output:**

```
Header: Supplementary Materials 
Paragraph: The workshop entitled “Next generation MRA (Microbiological Risk Assessment); integration of Omics data into assessment” took place in Athens, Greece, May 13-14, 2016, and resulted in four papers that are published in this issue, namely, Cocolin et al., Rantsiou et al., Den Besten et al., and Haddad et al. 

Header: Testing data
Paragraph: The supplementary materials, Table S1 and Table S2, are integrated parts of these four papers.

Header: Supplementary Materials 
Paragraph: The workshop entitled “Next generation MRA (Microbiological Risk Assessment); integration of Omics data into assessment” took place in Athens, Greece, May 13-14, 2016, and resulted in four papers that are published in this issue, namely, Cocolin et al., Rantsiou et al., Den Besten et al., and Haddad et al. 

Header: Testing data
Paragraph: The supplementary materials, Table S1 and Table S2, are integrated parts of these four papers.
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response...its working as expected